# No Matching Member Function to Call 'connect' - When Using 'this'

Tags: c++, qt, signals

My program was working fine but I wanted to add an extra signal into it to display an updated value. This is the first time the signal was actually coming from the class itself, so I decided to use `this` as you shall see.

### The Program

In my header file, as usual I declare my signal:

```
signals:
    void NotifyStatusUpdated(const QString& value);

private:

    SetupTab& m_setupTab;
    Instrument& m_instrument;
```

In the .cpp, the final thing constructed is the signal:

```
WireMessages();
emit NotifyStatusUpdated(tr("Long wait time (Ms) updated : %1 ").arg(long_wait));
```

Then below I have this:

```
void SetupViewManager::WireMessages()
{
    connect(&m_instrument, &Instrument::NotifyErrorDetected,
            &m_setupTab, &SetupTab::onStatusUpdated);       //this works
    connect(&m_instrument, &Instrument::NotifyStatusUpdated,
            &m_setupTab, &SetupTab::onStatusUpdated);       //this works
    connect(this, &Instrument::NotifyStatusUpdated,       //this does not work (it doesn't build)!
            &m_setupTab, &SetupTab::onStatusUpdated);
}
```

So in my class reference `m_instrument`, I have another signal which has the same name. So here I want to call the signal from `this` class instead.

### The Error

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
        connect(this, &Instrument::NotifyStatusUpdated,
        ^~~~~~~
```

This just does not seem right to me? What stupid mistake am I making?

Comment: `connect(this, &SetupViewManager::NotifyStatusUpdated` ?

Comment: yup, it's a stupid mistake

Comment: you know when you've been coding for so long that the screen starts to mould into one? And there's no one in the office around to look over a small section? yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` pointer is of `SetupViewManager` class in your code:

```
connect(this, &SetupViewManager::NotifyStatusUpdated, ...
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The joy of having a second pair of eyes when your 10th coffee doesn't help